# Java switch case delay

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm programming a little 2d game. Acutally I'm busy with the jumping-function. I want my player to jump, when i press the up-arrow key. I managed to make him jumping, but there is a delay of at least one second. This dealy is not existing for other actions like moving left or right. Do you know where it comes from?

The code for jumping is in the keyReaction method.

```
public class John<I> extends AbstractGame<I> {
//lists
List<ImageObject<I>> floor = new ArrayList<>();

//variables
double jumpHeight = 0;

//boolean
boolean jump = false;

//fix values
int blockHeight = 40;
int blockWidth = 40;

public John(double width, double height) {
    //getPlayer()
    super(new ImageObject<>("player.png", new Vertex(120, height - 200), new Vertex(0, 0)), width, height);

    //floor objects
    for(int i=0; i<getWidth(); i+=blockWidth)
        floor.add(new ImageObject<>("brick.png", new Vertex(i, getHeight() - blockHeight)));

    //add arrays to canvas
    getGOss().add(floor);
}

@Override
public void doChecks() {
    for(ImageObject<I> f:floor) {
        //gravity
        if(!(jump) && !(getPlayer().touches(f)))
            getPlayer().getMotion().y++;

        //stop y-motion on ground
        if(getPlayer().touches(f)){
            getPlayer().getPos().y = getHeight() - blockHeight - getPlayer().getHeight();
            getPlayer().getMotion().y = 0;}
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isStopped(){
    return false;
}

@Override
public void keyReaction(KeyCode keycode){
    switch (keycode) {
        //move left
        case LEFT_ARROW:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = -2;
            break;
        case VK_A:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = -2;
            break;
        //move right
        case RIGHT_ARROW:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = 2;
            break;
        case VK_D:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = 2;
            break;
        //jump
        case UP_ARROW:
            jump = true;
            if(jumpHeight < 100){
                jumpHeight += 5;
                getPlayer().getPos().y -=5;

            } else if (jumpHeight < 200){
                jumpHeight +=5;
                getPlayer().getPos().y +=5;
            }
            break;
        case VK_W:
            break;
        case SPACE:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReactionReleased(KeyCode keycode){
    switch (keycode) {
        //move left
        case LEFT_ARROW:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = 0;
            break;
        case VK_A:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = 0;
            break;
        //move right
        case RIGHT_ARROW:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = 0;
            break;
        case VK_D:
            getPlayer().getMotion().x = 0;
            break;
        //jump
        case UP_ARROW:
            jump = false;
            jumpHeight = 0;
            break;
        case VK_W:
            jump = false;
            break;
        case SPACE:
            break;
    }
}

//test main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new SwingScreen(new John<>(1800, 600)));
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Code with the if:

```
case UP_ARROW:
    if(jumpHeight < 20){
        jumpHeight += 5;
        getPlayer().getPos().y = -5;

    } else if (jumpHeight < 40){
        jumpHeight +=5;
        getPlayer().getPos().y = 5;
    }
    break;
```

Code without the if:

```
case UP_ARROW:
   getPlayer().getPos().y = -5;
   break;
```

KeyReaction:

```
setOnKeyPressed((ev)->{
    logic.keyReaction(KeyCode.fromCode(ev.getCode().impl_getCode()));
    ev.consume();
        });

setOnKeyReleased((ev)->{
    logic.keyReactionReleased(KeyCode.fromCode(ev.getCode().impl_getCode()));
    ev.consume();
        });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the switch statement. There is no magical delay when you use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jumpheight method you have

```
jump = true;
if(jumpHeight < 100){
  jumpHeight += 5;
  getPlayer().getPos().y -=5;
} else if (jumpHeight < 200){
  jumpHeight +=5;
  getPlayer().getPos().y +=5;
}
break;
```

On the 4th line there, you have a -=5 for the pos. There is likely another method that prevents the ypos from going under 0. What happens then is you press the up arrow, it gets sent 40 times(200/5), eventually the jumpheight is greater than 200, and only then does the player start moving up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The position of my player, before he jumps, is y=560. When the up-arrow-key is active the player should move to the upper side of the screen. I commented all the methods in doChecks() out to see if there is another method in my class, that prevents the player to move. 
The jumpheight is a variable I declared at the top of my classfile. It should start with 0, count up in +5 steps and be resettet if it reaches 200.
If i remove the "if" around it, the function works instantly. If I put a something like 1 == 1 as condition, it even has a delay.

Comment: Can you post your code with the "if" and code without?

Comment: Added it to my startpost

Comment: What is the purpose of the jumpheight variable

Comment: It goes over 40, but you  never reset it?

Comment: I reset it when the key is released. When I add my doChecks methods again, the y pos will be stopped as soon as the player touches the floor

Comment: You changed the getPos().y from -= 5 to =-5, is this intended?

Comment: Yes i wanted to make it work with the most simple case

Comment: For your original comment, what is the time of the delay?

Comment: It is around one second. I checked if it also happens with getPlayer().getMotion().y , but there was no delay. So it seems to be just a problem with the position

Comment: One thing this might be is the KeyReaction method, change that to a KeyPressed. It may be waiting for the key press event to fire twice.

Comment: Also how often are you repainting/redrawing the sprite/frame?

Comment: The repaint timer is set to 100, so it should repaint 10 times per second. I add my keyPressed, and keyReleased function in startpost

Comment: So you're saying that it delays even if you only have if(true){   getPlayer().getPos().y = -5;
}
break;

? I find that a bit difficult to believe.

Comment: yeah, but it depends on how high i set the y motion. If i set it to 20, it jumps 20px higher, waits for a short time (less than one second) and then fluently goes up the screen.

Comment: What is happening is that when you hold down a keyboard key, multiple key presses are being sent with a delay between them. (This can be seen when you type something like ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt). What you need to do instead is set booleans on when the key is pressed, and then unset them when they are released in order to overcome the default delays.